# Preview only gets updated in Endeca Exp Manager (11.2) on Publish, not save

Tags: atg, endeca

We are using ATG-Endeca Customer Store Reference integration 11.2. We have configured Preview and are able to see the changes reflected in the publishing store. However, the changes only get reflected after we Publish them using Experience Manager and not simply after saving. Is this expected behavior? Oracle states the following which seems like it is.

You need to configure your staging environment so that changes to Workbench content are automatically published to a generational store whenever the Workbench user saves them. The saved changes are immediately visible in Preview mode upon a successful publish.

Comment: Yes. Looks like there is issue with configuration. It should display the changes on preview on saving. On promote content it should push changes to live.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue in my project, i solve this adding endecapreview layer in my ear.

See this doc: Experience Manager Save & Preview Button Does Not Show Unpublished Workspace Changes (Doc ID 2230799.1) in Oracle Support.

Answer (score 0):

In Endeca 11.2 both the Preview/Authoring and live Web Apps use FileStores. When you save your configurations in the workbench only the Endeca Content Repository gets updated and not the FileStore used by the Preview/Authoring Web App. For that you have to publish the project (newly introduced in 11.2). To do this click the 'untitled work' link in your experience manager UI and click publish. This will write to the FileStore used by the Preview/Authoring Web App and the changes will be visible.